# Correctly Updating Div using Javascript and split

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

This is a mvc 3 razor vb.net application... I have the code behind doing everything fine so I decided to add a little more to the data coming in to the java so that the screen could be a little more informative about it's current progress... The string that getstatus has coming in is a string delimited with "/" where data.split("/")(0) = the integer in the function and data.split("/")(1) = the string to display in the currentEmail div... This is not working and it is simply because I am a total noob to javascript and i know it is possible..

```
@Code 
ViewData("Title") = "MassEmailSendingStatus"
TempData.Add("emList", TempData("emailaddresses"))
Dim x As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString
end Code

<div>
<a href="#" id="startProcess">Start Process</a>
</div>
<br />

<div id="currentEmail">

</div>
<div id="statusBorder">
<div id="statusFill">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uniqueId = '@x';
  var tdata = '@TempData("emailaddresses")';
          $(document).ready(function (event) {
          $('#startProcess').click(function () {
              $.post("MassEmailSendingStatus", { id: uniqueId }, function () {
              $('#statusBorder').show();
              getStatus();
          });
          event.preventDefault;
      });
  });

  function getStatus() {
      var url = 'GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
      $.get(url, function (data) {
          var str = data;
          var n1 = str.split("/");
          var v1 = integer.parseint(n1[0]);
          var v2 = n1[1];
          if (v1 != "100") {
              $('#status').html(data);
              $('#currentEmail').html(v2);
              $('#statusFill').width(v1);
              window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
          }
          else {
              $('#status').html("Done");
              $('#statusBorder').hide();
              alert("The Long process has finished");
          };
      });
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: [Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster](http://www.coderanch.com/t/456377/a/401/javascript-java.jpg)

Comment: lols but a hamster could be just as tasty.

Comment: ok, then car to carpet :D

Comment: lols but cars have carpet.. I'm playing but yeah i need help..

Comment: The point being, you'll want to avoid using a [tag:java] tag when your question has nothing to do with programming with the Java language.

Comment: oh noes.. I got the tag police on meh. Sorry for that it was poor judgement on my own ignorant self mannerisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on my own with some browser lvl debugging.. 
    `var v1 = integer.parseint(n1[0]);` is wrong it should be `var v1 = ParseInt(n1[0]);` case sensitive languages = not for noobs like meh.

```
 function getStatus() {
  var url = 'GetCurrentProgress/' + uniqueId;
  $.get(url, function (data) {
      var str = data;
      var n1 = str.split("/");
      var v1 = integer.parseint(n1[0]);
      var v2 = n1[1];
      if (v1 != "100") {
          $('#status').html(data);
          $('#currentEmail').html(v2);
          $('#statusFill').width(v1);
          window.setTimeout("getStatus()", 100);
      }
      else {
          $('#status').html("Done");
          $('#statusBorder').hide();
          alert("The Long process has finished");
      };
  });
```

}